# comparing cell value(numbers) in vba

Tags: vba, types, numbers

In vba i want have an if statement:

```
If Range("M" & i).Value*1000000 = Range("N" & i).Value Then
```

but for example when one is 82.608, the other one is 82608000, it's not matching each other, any idea why this is wrong?

Should I use CLng or CInt?

In Excel both M and N columns are formated as General.

Comment: You are falling prey to the floating point.  like you said try `If CLng(Range("M" & i).Value*1000000) = Range("N" & i).Value Then`

Comment: I got yours to work, copying the values and the code.

Comment: If you add more decimals, is the value `82.6079` or `82.608024`? In other words, is `82.608` the *actual value* of the cell, or just how Excel is displaying it with 3 decimals? `.Value` will return the *actual* cell value, not just its 3-decimal *representation*.

Comment: Got it ! thank u guys so much